# Asp.net connection string in web.config for OPD.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g

I have oracle database.I have installed oracle client.Added refrence of Oracle.DataAccess in visual studio 2012 and use two name spaces

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
and using following connection string in web.config
 <connectionStrings>



    <add name="Oracleconnect" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl.234.9.4)));User ID=hr;password=hr"
          providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
      </connectionStrings>

but when I run my application i get following error

ystem.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize() at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at SchoolsManagementSystem.DAL.GetConnection() in d:\c#\SchoolsManagementSystem\SchoolsManagementSystem\App_Code\DAL.cs:line 20 at SchoolsManagementSystem.DAL.AunthicateUser(String username, String password) in d:\c#\SchoolsManagementSystem\SchoolsManagementSystem\App_Code\DAL.cs:line 24 at SchoolsManagementSystem.Login.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\c#\SchoolsManagementSystem\SchoolsManagementSystem\Login.aspx.cs:line 46
```

Please guide me how can I solve this problem.Why the above error shows

Comment: The Client's version is match with your appliaction(eg.client is x86 and  you appcliation is x86)

Comment: How can I solve this problem